# Program received signal SIGILL trying stack smashing

Tags: c, gdb

---

I'm trying to complete a tutorial about exploiting a buffer overflow, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJ8IwyhqzD4. Everything seems to work, except at the end, the '/bin/sh' program isn't run, though I can see the no-op symbols and '/bin/sh' text.

The message should read "Process is executing new program: /bin/sh", but instead I get:

```
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0xb7e30a00 in __libc_start_main (main=0x804844d <main>, argc=3, 
argv=0xbffff0a4, init=0x8048490 <__libc_csu_init>, 
fini=0x8048500 <__libc_csu_fini>, rtld_fini=0xb7fed180 <_dl_fini>, 
stack_end=0xbffff09c) at libc-start.c:246
246 libc-start.c: No such file or directory.
```

I also get this same message when trying to find the edge of the buffer with this command in gdb:

```
run $(python -c "print('A'*268)").
```

Any help understanding this error is greatly appreciated. 
Michael

Comment: have you compiled without stack protector? (`-fno-stack-protector`)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I compiled it without the stack protector.

Comment: those exploits are cpu-dependent. Make sure you're not using x64 when you should use x64 for instance. You get SIGILL (illegal instruction) which means that your exploit executed _something_. Just not what you expected.

Comment: Consider using [capstone](https://www.capstone-engine.org/lang_python.html) to verify your assembly.

Comment: Thanks, Jean. At least I know something executed. Maybe it's the VM i'm using that's causing this.